# redirect url based on a string match htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

There are hundreds of urls are returning with server error.  Here is the example url

http://www.example.com/index.php?option=com_nap&format=raw&view=googlemapshow&vw_name=tabbed_compact&pid=12196

If I see an url with a string value as "com_nap", i need to redirect to my sub domain.

The above url should be redirected to

http://subdomain.example.com/index.php?option=com_nap&format=raw&view=googlemapshow&vw_name=tabbed_compact&pid=12196

How can I do that in htaccess.

regards,
Raja

Answer (score 1):

I assume your webserver runs apache and has the mod_rewrite enabled?
In this case, you could match the QUERY_STRING (part behind the ? mark) against a regular expression.

Like so:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_nap [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http://subdomain.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

1) You turn on the Rewrite Engine if its available
2) You check the QUERY_STRING wether it starts with option=com_nap
3) You redirect with a 301 to the subdomain